# underline a specific hyper link

Tags: hyperref, color, links, soul, hyperlink

I would be happy if anyone can help me to color differently only one specific hyperlink, (preferably, without setting `\hypersetup{}`. Many thanks in advance.

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{hyperref}


    \begin{document}
    {\setulcolor{red}\ul{Package Pomodoro CRAN:}}
    
    {\underline{\setulcolor{red}{\href{https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pomodoro/index.html}{WANNA UNDERLINE THIS BLACK TEXT WITH RED:}}}}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}


    \begin{document}
    {\setulcolor{red}\ul{Package Pomodoro CRAN:}}

    {\setulcolor{red}\ul{\mbox{\href{https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pomodoro/index.html}{WANNA UNDERLINE THIS BLACK TEXT WITH RED:}}}}

    \end{document}
```

And no, you can't avoid the \mbox. soul won't like it. If you want underlining with a linebreak you should either use \hypersetup or lualatex and the lua-ul package.